# Difference between elapsed time and aggregated time

Tags: time

In my timeline diagram, there are 3 items

1. 1st item started at 12Noon and finished at 2PM (2 Hrs)
2. 2nd item started at 3PM and finished at 6PM  (3 Hrs)
3. 3rd item started at 5PM and finished at 7PM (2 Hrs)

When descriping this timeline in a document how can i represet the total time? Example,

My total time : 12Noon to 7PM = 7Hrs
My active time : 12to2 and 3to7 = 6Hrs

My question is how to mention my total time and my active time? what are the correct phase to represent/differentiate those?

**elapsed time / aggregated time/ total time / anything else?**

*Note: Not mathematical question. Just an example illustration.*

Answer (score 1):

**Elapsed Time**--Elapsed time is the amount of time that has passed during a current, on-going event with a finite end. e.g, James Bond is trying to defuse a bomb that will turn him and his girlfriend into jelly in 2 minutes. He checks the timer and notes that 1 minute thirty seconds has elapsed.
**Aggregate time** is the accumulated time taken to accomplish several tasks of the same nature. The term is used in the sport of bobsledding, skiing, luge to describe the total time consumed on 4 runs down the bobsled course. e.g., the first run was finished in 1.057 minutes; the second run was finished in 1.0364 minutes for an aggregate time of 2.0934 minutes. 'Aggregate' is most often used as an adjective 'Aggregate' also appears in law, economics and demographics. e.g., Aggregate debts, liabilities; aggregate demand; aggregate unemployment rates.